# How to join two tables to determine date ranges when one table contains (id, start_date) and another contains (id, end_date)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm new to SQL, hope you guys don't find it silly. Working with two tables here, one contains start dates and other contains end dates. Entries do not follow sequence/possibility of duplicates.

```
**TABLE 1**
id  start_date
1   2019-04-23
1   2019-06-05
1   2019-06-05
1   2019-10-29
1   2019-12-16
2   2019-01-05
3   2020-02-01

**TABLE 2**
id  end_date
1   2019-04-23
1   2019-06-05
1   2019-06-06
1   2019-06-06
1   2019-07-24
1   2019-10-16
2   2020-01-04

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
id  start_date  end_date
1   2019-04-23  2019-06-05
1   2019-10-29  null
2   2019-01-05  2020-01-04
3   2020-02-01  null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `union all` and aggregation with some window functions:

```
with table1 as (
      select 1 as id, date('2019-04-23') as start_date union all
      select 1,   '2019-06-05' union all
      select 1,   '2019-06-05' union all
      select 1,   '2019-10-29' union all
      select 1,   '2019-12-16' union all
      select 2,   '2019-01-05' union all
      select 3,   '2020-02-01'
     ),
     table2 as (
      SELECT 1 as id, DATE('2019-04-23') as end_date union all
      SELECT 1,   '2019-06-05' union all
      select 1,   '2019-06-06' union all
      select 1,   '2019-06-06' union all
      select 1,   '2019-07-24' union all
      select 1,   '2019-10-16' union all
      select 2,   '2020-01-04'
     ) 
select id, min(start_date), end_date
from (select id, start_date,
         first_value(end_date ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by DATE_DIFF(coalesce(start_date, end_date), CURRENT_DATE, day) RANGE between 1 following and unbounded following) as end_date
      from ((select id, start_date, null as end_date
             from table1
            ) union all
            (select id, null as start_date, end_date
             from table2
            )
           ) se
     )
group by id, end_date
having min(start_date) is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have multiple records with the same id (Am assuming id is a primary key)? My suggestion would be for you to make the id's unique and creating a foreign key constraint in the end dates table (Since there can't be and end date without a start date) and use the foreign key relationship to retrieve the desired results. E.g SELECT S.start_date,E.end_date FROM table1 S JOIN table2 E where S.id=E.table1_fk

Comment: People who designed this treated these tables like an audit trail. I understand what you saying but it is what it is, looking for the resolution without changing the existing table structure.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT id, start_date, IF(end_date = '9999-01-01', NULL, end_date) end_date
FROM (
  SELECT id, start_date, ARRAY_AGG(end_date ORDER BY end_date LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] end_date
  FROM (
    SELECT id, start_date, IF(start_date < end_date, end_date, '9999-01-01')  end_date
    FROM `project.dataset.table1` 
    LEFT JOIN `project.dataset.table2`
    USING (id)
  )
  GROUP BY id, start_date
)
```

If to apply to sample data from your question - result is

```
Row id  start_date  end_date     
1   1   2019-04-23  2019-06-05   
2   1   2019-06-05  2019-06-06   
3   1   2019-10-29  null     
4   1   2019-12-16  null     
5   2   2019-01-05  2020-01-04   
6   3   2020-02-01  null
```

Note: quick and not optimized - but looks like produces desired result

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really appreciate it.